# Creating an interactive quiz

Tags: jquery, html, interactive

I'm trying to create a quiz that lets users answer questions such as name & sex. I've used  and  in html but now I want it so that when the user clicks 'submit' that data will be put into a paragraph like a mail merge.

For example;

> name: Dave
>
> Sex: Male

Click submit and text appears;

> There once was a **Male** named **Dave**

so far my code for the form is;

```
<form method= "get" action="Results.html" target="_blank">
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="">Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="">Female<br>
  Name:<input type="text" name="" id="name"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

I don't even know if what I'm trying to do is possible, everything I've looked up I can't get to work. Any help would be appreciated, thank you

*edit*

Some of the jquery I'm playing around with;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var text = '<p>Oh my god, I can't believe what<b>';
  text +=$('input[name=name] :checked').val();
  text +='</b>named<b>';
  var text = 'did last night. How do you get that drunk?';
  text += '</b></p>';
  $('#results').append(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not determined to have your paragraph open in a different window then this could be done quite easily with jQuery

```
var text = '<p>There once was a <b>';
text += $('input[name=sex] :checked').val();
text += '</b> named <b>';
text += $('#name').val();
text += '</b></p>';

$('#ResultsDiv').append(text);
```

You're going to have to play with this a little bit, opening the paragraph in a new window will be tricky. You're also going to have to add a [jQuery](http://jquery.com) reference to your header.

Comment: That seems great, thank you. I'm going to play around with the code a bit like you say but I think I can get this to work. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to start looking at server-side languages, although this could also be achieved by using JavaScript and having the quiz client-side, which means the conditions and form handling is done on the browser itself.

For server-side, you could look at:

- PHP
- Ruby/Ruby on Rails
- Go
- Node.js

Since we don't write the code for you here, I advise that you start looking at one of those technologies to get you started. Once you're all setup and tried to give this a go, show us your code and we can help then.

Comment: Thank you, I started looking into Ruby but it might be a while before I'm able to do something like this.